# overlapping line and bar charts at the dame time with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Would like to overlap a line chart over a bar chart with ggplot.
Say, V1, V2 are the data for the bar charts, and V3 shall be presented as line.
How can I complete the subset and different geom at the same time?

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(100)
dat <- data.frame(Axis=letters[1:10],V1=1:10, V2=runif(10, 1,10), V3=10:1)
dat <-melt(data,id.var="Axis",measure.var=c("V1","V2","V3"))
```

Would it be like this?

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=Axis)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(, y= value[------]))+   # V1, V2 for bars
geom_line(aes(y=value[-----))                         # V3 for line
```

I tried making the subset of V1, V2, and make a bar chart, but can't insent V3 as a line on the chart.

Many thanks

Thanks to @dash2, I slightly changed his code, and make it looks clearer.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = Axis)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = V1), fill = "darkred", alpha = .5, width=0.4) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = V2), fill = "blue", alpha = .5, 
           position = position_nudge(x = 0.4),width=0.4) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = V3, group = NA))
```

[image]

Comment: I always appreciate question with minimal reproducible code. It makes things very easy.

Comment: You could edit my answer to preserve the separation between questions and answers....

Comment: Grec001 I think @dash2 is correct. You could have edited his answer and keep the question clear. It would be good for future users. Also please add legends to that graph otherwise its not looking good. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest, no melting.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Axis)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = V1), fill = "darkred", alpha = .5) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = V2), fill = "blue", alpha = .5, 
        position = position_nudge(x = 0.2)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = V3, group = NA))
```

[image]

Add aesthetics to taste.

The `group` argument is necessary. I think that discrete scales (like the x axis here) automatically group their values, leaving you with groups of 1 and no lines being drawn... consistent, but unintuitive.

Comment: `ggplot(dat, aes(x = Axis)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = V1), fill = "darkred", alpha = .5, width=0.4) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = V2), fill = "blue", alpha = .5, 
           position = position_nudge(x = 0.4),width=0.4) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = V3, group = NA))`

Comment: That's a good approach. The only problem I can see in this approach is that `legends` are not shown. How to distinguish between V1 & V2?

Comment: Add a legend. Though I admit, doing so is hard to remember in `ggplot`.

Answer (score 1):

No need to `melt` your data, just simply add different aesthetics to each `geom`:

```
data <- data.frame(Axis=letters[1:10], V1=1:10, V2=runif(10, 1,10), V3=10:1)

ggplot(data, aes(x = V1)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = V2)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = V3))
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Thanks! It seems closer, and I tried this early. But it would be impossible to tell V1 and V2, due to they are overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(100)
data <- tibble(Axis=letters[1:10],V1=1:10, V2=runif(10, 1,10), V3=10:1)
data <-melt(data,id.var="Axis",measure.var=c("V1","V2","V3"))
glimpse(data)
ggplot(data, aes(x=Axis, y= data$value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but I need to make the V3 a line overlapping on the bars composed by V1 and V2.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be with `melt` data as:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(100)
data <- data.frame(Axis=letters[1:10],V1=1:10, V2=runif(10, 1,10), V3=10:1)
data <-melt(data,id.var="Axis",measure.var=c("V1","V2","V3"))

library(dplyr)
ggplot() +
geom_bar(data=filter(data, variable %in% c("V1", "V2")), 
 aes(x = Axis, y = value, fill=variable), stat ="identity", position="dodge") +
  geom_line(data=filter(data, variable == "V3"), 
      aes(x = Axis, y = value, colour = variable, group=variable))
```

[image]